# How to identify Dialectisms?

Tags: expressions

In the following paragraph can you tell me if there are dialecticism (a dialectal expression)?

> Besides, in establishing the field school, the diagnosis included the initial study and the sensitization meeting for the field school presentation.

Comment: Have you looked up the word?? In any event, your sentence does not make much sense as written. Try: idiomatic expression. dialects, dialectical. the ism one is not accurate.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please note that requests for help with phrasing or finding errors are not accepted here. Stack Exchange prefers questions and answers which are applicable to many people where there can be a single best answer; open-ended proofreading requests cannot meet this standard. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: That said, your problem here is not that the English represents a particular dialect, but that it is not natural in *any* dialect—it sounds artificial, like an academic affectation or like "[Euro-English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_English)." I don't understand what a "diagnosis" would have to do with a "sensitization meeting," whatever that is. At the least, some additional context is required to understand what you are trying to express.

Comment: @choster. Thanks for your reply ann recommendation for my first time here.
I was looking synonyms for baseline studies. Seems that diagnosis is not recommended.
Thanks again